# redirecting html when flash not installed

Tags: html, flash, redirect, indexing

ok I have searched and read lots of posts on this topic, however I dont feel I have found an answer to my specific situation.

I have already inserted a forward if a mobile phone is being used to a mobile site, however what I want to do is this:

This is a Flash only site, if flash is not installed they wont see anything,(at this time) what I would like is for the browser they are using (regardless of what browser it is) to detect if they have flash installed and if not then to redirect them to a version of the website that is html.

How do i do that with this index.html file?? All answers are greatly appreciated :)

[image of current HMTL page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW4zF.jpg)

Comment: You can use [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to detect if your user's browser has flash player or not ...

Comment: is there a way of doing it without altering the current coding? except to the redirect?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "altering your code", but you can add the [swfobject flash player detection](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion(versionStr)) before creating your swf, if you have flash player, so create the swf otherwise redirect your user to another page.

Comment: how would i do this? i didnt create the swf file, the html page is above in image form so i am looking for a html way to do this, if possible